# How to lauch some external app from my service and do some actions in it?

Tags: android, bots

I want to launch youtube (for example) from my app and initiate some actions on it (tap to x,y, drag from point to point) and the get screenshot from it. How can I do this? I found out selendroid but it is only possible to use it only for my own app and only when my device is connected to my PC via USB. Need to write a bot to external app.

Thanks

Comment: In general, that is not possible, for obvious security reasons.

The only thing that you have available outside of development tools (e.g., Selendroid) is the set of accessibility APIs. AFAIK, they will not allow you to do what you seek, but you are welcome to examine them.

Rooted devices and custom ROMs would offer other avenues to explore.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygery.repetitouch.pro this app can do it

Comment: The third word in that app's name is "root". You are welcome to root your device, in which case more options will become available to you for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: For example you can open whatsapp with `Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(launchIntent);`